# Loading custom view from XIB always stays with same frame inside stack view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, uistackview

I made a custom `UIView` in a xib and loaded as :

```
class func instanceFromNib() -> ExclusiveCollectionView {
    return UINib(nibName: "ExclusiveCollectionView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! ExclusiveCollectionView
}
```

The custom view also got a subview - UIcollection view object.
Now when I tried to load in the parent which contains a stack view.
In parent controller, viewWillAppear

```
    let customView  = ExclusiveCollectionView.instanceFromNib()
    myStackView.addArrangedSubview(customView)
```

The custom view always stays with **Frame Rectangle** frame. For instance frame rectangle width in xib is 320 for iphone 5s, then after loading in stackview view still stays in 320 instead of 414 for iPhone 8 Plus.

**iPhone 5S :**

[image]

**iPhone 8 Plus :**

[image]

I know this is a common issue, already solved by SO champs. But anyhow I am not able to find the working solution. I am using Swift 4.1 with XCODE 9.0.1 tested in iPhone 5S and iPhone 8 Plus.

//Update : I tried to add after updating frame in viewDidLayoutSubview as given in many SO answers. But it is not working.

I have created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/byJeevan/133231bd089a09fef87ed619d0d39428) for the same questions for more clarity.

Comment: Try implementing sizeForItemAtIndexPath function of collectionview flow layout.

Comment: @shubham I have already tried with sizeForItemAtIndexPath delegate, gives same result because... the problem  is with customview+collectionview frame, which is essentially used to calculate the cell items size.

Comment: Is this problem with the way loading XIB ?